# update a row without sql triggers

Tags: mysql

I have a table called tasks and in it are tasks for users to complete. is it possible to make a task that is complete if all other tasks for that user are complete. I know I can do this with SQL triggers but I wanted to know if there's a more elegant way to do this.

this includes making a new task and therefore making the final task incomplete

Comment: No, you must use triggers... or make it part of the code that marks the tasks complete (in whatever language you are using). There's nothing wrong with triggers

Comment: Is it necessary to store this special "task" in the database?  Can't you simply determine its status using a grouping/aggregation `SELECT` query?